# Validate number with outlying number possibility in class-validator

Tags: typescript, validation, decorator, class-validator

I have a field in my class that looks like so:

```
@IsDefined()
@IsInt()
@Min(1)
@Max(10)
someNumber: number;
```

I'd like `someNumber` to also be able to be assigned `-1`. How can I incorporate this without making a custom validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the `NotEquals` with the `Min` decorator:

```
@IsDefined()
@IsInt()
@NotEquals(0)
@Min(-1)
@Max(10)
someNumber: number;
```